# Get between curly braces including the first and the last curly braces

Tags: javascript, regex

Code I have:

[Click here to see the code](https://regexr.com/3t6s0)

I want to get between (including) the first curly braces to the last (including):

```
<html lang=3D"pl-US"> <head> </head> <body> <div>  <script data-scope=3D"in=
boxmarkup" type=3D"application/json">{
  "api_version": "1.0",
  "publisher": {
    "api_key": "61d9",
    "name": "Google Alerts"
  },
  "entity": {
    "external_key": "Google Alert - Adidas"
  },
  "updates": {
    "snippets": [ {
      "icon": "BOOKMARK",
      "message": "lala (Nike)"
    } ]
  },
  "cards": [ {
    "title": "Google Alert - Adidas",
    "subtitle": "Nike and Adidas",
    "actions": [ {
      "name": "Sam",
      "url": "https://www.google.com"} ],
    "widgets": [ {
      "type": "LINK",
      "title": "lala (Nike)"
    } ]
  } ]
}
</script> <!--[if mso]>
 <table><tr><td width=3D650>
<![endif]-->
```

When I use `\{([^()]|())*\}`, it returns me weird one that doesn't include all (shown in the code). The plan is to parse the data and use as JSON.

I only need everything between (including) first occurrence of `{` and last occurrence of `}`.

Comment: which programming environment/language are you using?

Comment: @trincot, javascript

Comment: Try `{.*}(?=$)` [here](https://regex101.com/r/c0sAeH/2)

Comment: @AmazingDayToday `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: Then use JavaScript's built in `JSON.parse`

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @JonasW., I know that parsing HTML is not a good idea, but I really need it. :-)

Comment: Parsing JSON with Regex is also not a good idea, and no you don't need bad ideas.

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong with parsing it right off the bat.

Comment: @Hatchet, I understand that JSON.parse() would work, if... there was no many other symbols. Please see the link.

Comment: Wtf. I just realized that You are actually trying to parse JSON *inside* HTML with Regex.

Comment: @JonasW., yes, sir!

Comment: I only need everything between (including) first occurrence of `{` and last occurrence of `}`.

Comment: [*Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”  Now they have two problems.* - Jamie Zawinski](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)

Comment: Please feel free to recommend better ways to get what I want. I mean if you think parsing HTML is not a good idea. Thanks.